# MVc error with EF

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3

I create a model that hasnt any relation to another tables with EF.
when I add it in the context and run app for create database i had an Error in Application-start:

**One or more validation errors were detected during model generation:
    System.Data.Edm.EdmEntityType: : EntityType 'UrlHelper' has no key defined. Define the key for this EntityType.
    System.Data.Edm.EdmEntityType: : EntityType 'RequestContext' has no key defined. Define the key for this EntityType.
    System.Data.Edm.EdmEntityType: : EntityType 'HttpContextBase' has no key defined. Define the key for this EntityType.
    System.Data.Edm.EdmEntityType: : EntityType 'Exception' has no key defined. Define the key for this EntityType.
    System.Data.Edm.EdmEntityType: : EntityType 'Type' has no key defined. Define the key for this EntityType.**

Code in my global.asax is like below:

```
    public class MyInitializer
: DropCreateDatabaseIfModelChanges<DBTa>
    {
    }
    protected void Application_Start()
    {
        //for creating and initializing database 
        System.Data.Entity.Database.SetInitializer(new MyInitializer());
        **DBTa db = new DBTa();**//Error shows here
        db.Database.Initialize(true);
        //

        AreaRegistration.RegisterAllAreas();

        RegisterGlobalFilters(GlobalFilters.Filters);
        RegisterRoutes(RouteTable.Routes);
    }
```

but when i removed model from app my problem solved, but i need this Model.

please help 
thanks a lot

Answer (score 0):

You should set "key" property in your `'UrlHelper'` model.
If you use EF code first - in your model you should add attribute `[Key]` to one of its properties.
If you use model first approach - in your model you should mark one of properties as primary key.
If you use Database first approach - you should create primary key in table.

Comment: thanks alot for your help i used from code first.but idont know where i should add attribute key.All classes have primary key .

Comment: I solved my problem . i used from (public class MyClass:controller) and it was wrong so i changed it to (public class MyClass).